# How do you get a reference to the default credential object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of machines that a need to create a PsSession object for. Some of the machines require my default credentials, while others need a customized credential object.

How do get a reference to the default credential object used in the PS commands
when you do not provide the `-credential` argument? I would like the following
commands to perform the same result.

```
new-pssession $SERVER
new-pssession $SERVER -credential $DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply grab the current user's credentials and store them in an object, the API won't let you. See [Get current user's credentials object in Powershell without prompting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917779/get-current-users-credentials-object-in-powershell-without-prompting)