# Impersonate user with powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, impersonation

Is it possible to impersonate using Powershell script. Like C# straight forward functions

```
   dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
    WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, ref hUserToken)
```

are there any functions in powershell doing same tasks as above.

I want to get token of current user who is "logged in and have desktop interactive session running".

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its not possible out of the box.

> The Windows API will not expose the information you need, which is why
> Powershell can't get to them. Its an intentional feature of the
> security subsystem. The only way for this to work is for the Linux
> machines to trust the calling machine, such as joining them to an
> Active Directory (or any kerberos setup really).
>
> Aside from that, you'd need to store and pass this information
> somehow.
>
> You could store the RSA key in the user's keystore and extract it at
> runtime (using the .NET Crypto/Keystore libs), so you aren't storing
> the key around with the code. That way the key itself would be
> protected by the OS and available only when the calling user was
> authenticated. You'd have one more thing to install, but may be the
> only way to achieve what you are aiming for.

-Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917779/get-current-users-credentials-object-in-powershell-without-prompting)

Using this method + the `qwinsta` command to get the active sessions will somehow get you the needed information you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course possible via pinvoke and embedded C# code.
But the main hurdle is the fact, that you can call WTSQueryUserToken only as "local system". You could grab the process-token from the "SamSs" service for instance to make this call work.