# Ask for creds only if some specified

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials

I'm trying to create a module with a bunch of functions, but I'm stuck with a problem: sometimes I need to run functions with a different from current credentials. But the thing is: I don't want to ask for credentials if I didn't specify a username. Like this:

```psh
function MyFunction ($ComputerName='localhost', $UserName) {
    if ($UserName) {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $UserName
    } else {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    }
}
```

Can I somehow get rid of the `if` statement? Can I just let the function use current credentials unless I specify `-UserName`?

If I leave it like this:

```psh
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $UserName
```

and call a function without specifying `-UserName`, it asks for credentialls every time. Yes, it uses current if I close the 'get-cred' box, but it's not what I want.

Comment: May I ask exactly what's wrong with using the "if"?  Since Get-WmiObject is an internal MS cmdlet I'm not sure you'll find any easier way to perform what you're attemping to do :).

Comment: This function is only for example. Not all of them are that simple (none of them actually). Trying to avoid wrapping really big expressions into 'if-else' statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can populate a `PSCredential` object with current credentials using the default credential acquired like [in here](http://vwiki.co.uk/Credentials_%28PowerShell%29):</s>

```
if ($UserName) {
   $cred = get-credential $username # this prompts for credentials
} else {
   $cred=[PSCredential][System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
}
```

Then just use `-credential $cred` whenever you need without building a wall of if's.

EDIT: Apparently, as the current user's `PSCredential` object has its password as `SecureString` encrypted by the very same user's private key, if one would be able to get a `PSCredential` out of default credentials object, he'll be able to decrypt the password into plaintext, so this hole existed but was eventually closed. (Maybe let this answer hang here so that people won't get the asme error as I did) [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917779/get-current-users-credentials-object-in-powershell-without-prompting) has the canonical answer on what arised in here.

Another way to do this might be using a variation of splatting, explained in detail by Ansgar Wiechers and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) to construct only credential block in a single if statement and then use that block wherever you need, instead of writing direct `-credential` parameter.

```
$creds=@{}
if ($UserName) {
   $cred = get-credential $username # this prompts for credentials
   $creds['Credential']=$cred
}
```

And then add @creds wherever you require alternate credentials:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName @creds
```

This way you'll be asked for user's password once if `$UserName` is supplied, and then the `$creds` will either be empty or contain valid credentials of `$UserName`, so all subsequent if's can be replaced by explicit adding of `@creds`.

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to work? Trying to cast `[PSCredential][System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials` threw an invalid cast exception for me.

Comment: I receive the following error on this: `Cannot convert the "System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential" value of type "System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential" to type "System.M
anagement.Automation.PSCredential".`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did it two-step, first into a variable, then into a PSCredential, and yes, it did create a valid PSCredential for me. Powershell 4.0, though. Maybe PS2.0 won't be able to do this.

Comment: Okay, I've apparently messed up my local vars with this. Pity. On the other hand, there's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917779/get-current-users-credentials-object-in-powershell-without-prompting) that states you can't get default creds without prompting. Weird tho. I'd rather make those cmdlets accept a `NetworkCredential` object to avoid this case.

Comment: Yep I was wrong. See updated answer. This one is based on @AnsgarWiechers one but is a tad better to only create a variable parameter set into hashtable to be splatted, so you don't need to build the whole parameter set each time you need alternate credentials.

Comment: Edited answer really works! That's the thing i needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) for dynamically building a parameter list, but you'd still need an `if` statement to decide whether or not to add the `-Credential` parameter:

```psh
function MyFunction ($ComputerName='localhost', $UserName) {
    $params = @{
      Class        = 'Win32_OperatingSystem'
      ComputerName = $ComputerName
    }
    if ($UserName) { $params['Credential'] = $UserName }

    Get-WmiObject @params
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your never really going to lose the `IF`, but you could create a string on the fly and then invoke it as and expression:

If `$UserName` is `$null` the credential parameter will not be added to the expression.

```
function MyFunction ([String]$ComputerName='localhost', [String]$UserName) {

    Invoke-Expression ("Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName $(IF($UserName){'-Credential $UserName'})")

}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, check if supplying an invalid value for `$Username` won't result in Powershell injection into the command. `"Robert"; Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -scope LocalMachine -force; #` for example must not trigger the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` calling.

Comment: @Vesper I have just tried it and it looks like you can tag any command onto the end of the string, if run outside the function. But if you set the parameters of the function to only except strings this stops the injection.

Comment: Hehe, it's just a reflex, if there's evaluatable expression, check if an injection is possible. This thing is dangerous, because Powershell deals with server management up close and personal, and often runs under administrative privileges (manual mode or scripted tasks), so an injection can literally destroy an organization structure if allowed to happen.