# Can I use the same WMI command whether credentials are provided or not?

Tags: powershell, security, wmi, powershell-2.0, credentials

WMI commands can either receive explicit credentials as an argument (the `-Credential` flag), or run in the security context of the user running the script if no credentials are provided.

Right now, my script looks like this:

```
if ($Creds) { # if the user provided credentials
    Invoke-WMIMethod -Credential $Creds <...something...>
    ... hundreds more lines of Invoke-WMIMethod code ...
else { # user did not supply credentials, use current security context
    Invoke-WMIMethod <...something...>
    ... same exact hundreds of lines of Invoke-WMIMethod code, without -Credential .... 
}
```

In other words, the only difference is the `-Credential` flag. Is there any way I can consolidate this huge if-else into one block of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/3.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Splatting) for dynamically passing arguments to a cmdlet, like this:

```
$params = @{
  'Class'        = 'Win32_Foo'
  'ComputerName' = 'bar'
  ...
}

if ($cred) {
  $params['Credential'] = $cred
}

Invoke-WmiMethod @params
```

or like this:

```
$optional_params = @{}
if ($cred) {
  $optional_params['Credential'] = $cred
}

Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Foo -Computer bar ... @optional_params
```

The technique should [already be available in PowerShell v2.0](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/).

Comment: So, using the second example, if I add `@optional_params` to the end of every `Invoke-WMIMethod`, then it will only add `-Credential $Cred` if I assign it a value like you did?

Comment: How about you just *try* it and see for yourself?

Comment: The reason I ask is because of the performance implications. I imagine this adds more overhead than the other solution proposed.

Comment: Run both kinds of statements a couple hundred or thousand times and measure execution time. Then compare the results and you'll know without any of us having to speculate about it. It really is as simple as that.

Comment: I would argue that asking a question about performance is within scope of determining the best answer for a question. In most cases, performance is not a matter of speculation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not seem to work, because it evaluates to "$null" when no username/password are given.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers's code should work fine if used properly. Put up a sample of your code if you think it's not. You don't want to set the Hashtable key/value entry at all if your credential isn't meant to be specified.  Setting it with a `$null` value will be just like specifying `-Credential $null`.  The performance implications will be negligible, but as Ansgar points out, the only way to evaluate it for your specific situation is for you to measure it in *your* specific situation...

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning Please provide evidence. Update your question with the code that "evaluates to $null". Include all errors you're getting.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I created an updated question addressing your splatting suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301329/splatting-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the current security context is available to be passed in as a credential object ([ref this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917779/get-current-users-credentials-object-in-powershell-without-prompting)).

Fortunately, invoke-wmimethod's use of the credential attribute appears to behave as if it wasn't specified when provided a null value.  So if `$cred` is empty then `invoke-wmimethod -credential $cred <...something...>` should behave the same as `invoke-wmimethod <...something...>`.

Now, even better might be just to keep the `if else` and remove any duplicate code.  So, instead of:

```
if ($Creds) { # if the user provided credentials
    Invoke-WMIMethod -Credential $Creds <...something...>
    ... hundreds more lines of code ...
else { # user did not supply credentials, use current security context
    Invoke-WMIMethod <...something...>
    ... same exact hundreds of lines of code .... 
}
```

You would have:

```
if ($Creds) { # if the user provided credentials
    $myresults = Invoke-WMIMethod -Credential $Creds <...something...>
else { # user did not supply credentials, use current security context
    $myresults = Invoke-WMIMethod <...something...>
}


    ... hundreds more lines of code using $myresults...
```

Comment: Well, it produces a pop-up prompt for credentials something like 50 times (one for each Invoke-WMIMethod command, I imagine). So this wont work. However, once I cancel out of all them it seems to produce the expected output. Is there a way I can disable the prompt, or (better yet) provide a value that wont produce a prompt?

Comment: Maybe try setting the `$Cred` variable to `$null` if the user doesn't supply credentials.

Comment: Didn't work either. I'll keep looking for a solution.