# Splatting - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, wmi, dynamic-programming

I can't seem to get my splatting to work in my `Invoke-WmiMethod` command. I declare the hash table like so:

```
$HKU = 2147483651

$MyParams = @{
  'Class' = 'StdRegProv';
  'Name' = 'EnumKey';
  'ArgumentList' = "$HKU,''";
  'ComputerName' = '';
}

# additional code determining ComputerName... #

$MyParams['ComputerName'] = $MyComputer;
$Vals = Invoke-WmiMethod @MyParams
```

This line gives me the following error:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod : Input string was not in a correct format.
At C:\Users\Person\Desktop\tmp.ps1:160 char:20
+         $Vals = Invoke-WmiMethod @MyParams
```

Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `argumentlist` so it's an array not a string

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Looks like Mark answered, otherwise I'd agree on the close.

Comment: @BenH That worked! Fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$HKU = 2147483651

$MyParams = @{
  'Class' = 'StdRegProv';
  'Name' = 'EnumKey';
  'ArgumentList' = @($HKU,'');
  'ComputerName' = '';
}

$MyParams['ComputerName'] = $MyComputer;
$Vals = Invoke-WmiMethod @MyParams
```

Comment: Source: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2010/12/16/invoking-wmi-methods-in-powershell/

"There’s a casting problem, according to the help of the ArgumentList parameter the value of the parameter must be an array of objects,"